# Select Omnigraffle control points hidden underneath selection handles

Tags: selection, shapes, omnigraffle

I have a custom shape in OmniGraffle 6. I don't know how to select the control points (little blue diamonds) because they are hidden underneath the object selection handles (little white squares). How can I do this?

I've added an example OmniGraffle shape below, showing some arbitrarily close control points and selection handles for the point of illustration. In my real example, the control points are completely covered.

[image: Example OmniGraffle Shape]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to Opt + Cmd + Click on the point you want to move. This will allow you to move the point without activating the selection handle.

Found on https://support.omnigroup.com/documentation/en/omnigraffle-6-for-mac/using-the-tools